# How to set transient variable for Activiti when starting process

Tags: variables, activiti, bpmn

I am using Activiti version 6.0.0 and trying to set transient variables when starting process or completing task. [Documentation for transient variables](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#apiTransientVariables) states:

> Transient variables can be got and/or set in most places where regular variables are exposed:
>   1. On DelegateExecution in JavaDelegate implementations
>   2. On DelegateExecution in ExecutionListener implementations and on DelegateTask on TaskListener implementations
>   3. In script task via the execution object
>   **4. When starting a process instance via the runtime service**
>   5. When completing a task
>   6. When calling the runtimeService.trigger method

Cases 1 - 3 are clear to me. For case 5 there is `taskService.complete(taskId, variables, transientVariables);` for case 6 there is `runtimeService.trigger(executionId, processVariables, transientVariables);` 
 but there is no `runtimeService.startProcess...` method accepting transient variables ([RuntimeService javadoc](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/6.latest/org/activiti/engine/runtimeservice)):

[image: List of available startProcess... methods]
Also I did not find a way to set transient variable after I start process and I have `ProcessInstance` object returned by `startProcess...` method.

Is there a way to set transient variables when starting process or do I have to use workaround (cases 1 or 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set transient variables on start in 6.x by using [a slightly different method for starting the process](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/29e3052f1a5afb2867a3cbee0910167e4f8c6806/modules/activiti-engine/src/test/java/org/activiti/engine/test/api/variables/TransientVariablesTest.java#L199):

```
runtimeService.createProcessInstanceBuilder()
        .processDefinitionKey("transientVarsTest")
        .transientVariable("variable", "gotoA")
        .start()
```